# Livewire always return error 500 in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables, laravel-livewire

I have project that is created in Laravel 6, so now i have to implement Livewire datatables in this project.
When i open the main page, everything is ok and table is rendered with the required data, when i try to click on `wire:click="sortBy('last_name')"` black iframe is returned.
I have checked the Network Activity with Chrome dev tools and found that i have `Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error` on `Request URL: http://app.test/livewire/message/backend.users-table`

#### UsersTable.php

```
class UsersTable extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $userRepository;
    protected $request;

    public $sortBy = 'last_name';
    public $sortDirection = 'asc';

    public function mount(UserRepository $userRepository, ManageUserRequest $request)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $searchQuery = ($this->request->has('q')) ? $this->request->input('q') : null;

        return view('backend.auth.user.includes.users-table')
            ->withUsers($this->userRepository->getActivePaginated(25, $this->sortBy, $this->sortDirection, $searchQuery));
    }

    public function sortBy($column)
    {
        if ($this->sortDirection == 'asc') {
            $this->sortDirection = 'desc';
        } else {
            $this->sortDirection = 'asc';
        }
        return $this->sortBy($column);
    }
}
```

#### getActivePaginated()

```
public function getActivePaginated($paged = 25, $orderBy = 'created_at', $sort = 'desc', $q) : LengthAwarePaginator
{
    return $this->model
        ->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
        ->with('roles', 'permissions', 'providers')
        ->active()
        ->orderBy($orderBy, $sort)
        ->paginate($paged);
}
```

#### users-table.blade.php

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th wire:click="sortBy('last_name')" class="cursor-pointer">
                @lang('labels.backend.access.users.table.last_name')
                @include('backend.auth.user.includes.users-table-sorting', ['column' => 'last_name'])
            </th>
            <th wire:click="sortBy('first_name')" class="cursor-pointer">
                @lang('labels.backend.access.users.table.first_name')
                @include('backend.auth.user.includes.users-table-sorting', ['column' => 'first_name'])
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $user->last_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->first_name }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

#### index.blade.php

```
@section('content')
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">

        @livewire('backend.users-table')

    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: What is the error message? 500 is very generic, the error logs will tell you exactly what is wrong and where.

Comment: Nothing in error logs... everything is clear

Comment: Your `sortBy` function has an infinite loop. Should probably be `$this->sortBy = $column;` rather than `return $this->sortBy($column);`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an exception for 'livewire/message/component-name' into app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

Comment: Please share some code to improve answer.